# Android unable to load class error

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to implement pull-to-refresh using github example https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh but when i am tring to implement the list view its giving me unable to load class master\library\src\com\handmark\pulltorefresh\library\pullToRefreshListView

```
I have imported library project into system and also placed the jar file.
```

I ran sample project which is using this library its working the screen shot of it is:

[image]

But when i am trying to implement this class to my project its giving class not found exception i have made one libs folder and put library.jar file in there and added it to build path but still on run time its throwing this error.

[image]

in my xml file i have put

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:divider="#E4E4E4"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
```

Comment: Something is wrong with either how you've imported it or how you're using it.  Can you post some code where you're using it, and describe how you imported it into your project?

Comment: try to click on the <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView tag if it is not navigate you to com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView class that means library is not imported in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution of it

in place of adding jar files in lib and adding it to build path we have to put library project as dependent project

You have to add project here

RightClick:==> properties ==> Android ==>> Library (Add)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you link the libs correctly?please check your IDE or your project.properties.